# paperclips in NatTable

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I am new to NatTable and was looking  to print the NatTable.

I know about paperClips for SWT tables but couldn't find anything similar for Nattable.
has anyone tried printing or even saving the Nattable data as imagedata?

Answer (score 1):

You can press CTRL+P while the NatTable has focus. This should give you a print dialog.

In code it will create a new PrintAction. Check out:
org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.print.action.PrintAction to see how that works.

Answer (score 1):

That's true in case you are using a GridLayer with DefaultGridLayerConfiguration. There the DefaultPrintBindings are aggregated which add the binding for CTRL+P.

Also the PrintCommandHandler is registered against the GridLayer.

So if you are using a GridLayer, the above statement is perfectly correct, otherwise you need to ensure to register the PrintCommandHandler and the corresponding binding to your layer composition.